# Trigger a Function on PageLoad

Tags: jquery, events, triggers, onload, sliding

I've a code that works for slide a hidden div with clicking another div

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
  });
});
</script>
```

But I want to remove "flip" div. I don't want to click for sliding. Sı I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
});
```

but didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: can u create  a jsfiddle for ur issue...for me its working...http://jsfiddle.net/bN4fM/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try on page load

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
});
```

Visit: http://justprogrammer.com/

Comment: tried and worked thanks. Can we make some latency for this? Edit: I've found it too, thanks for your help